# How to obtain ALL the combinations with repetition of the elements of a list - prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to get all the combinations with repetition of all the elements in a list L . These elements need to be returned in a size N list. (L, N, CWR).

The expected result would be something like:

```
?-([red,blue,green], 2 , X).

X = [red, red] ;
X = [red, blue] ;
X = [red, green] ;
X = [blue, blue] ;
X = [blue, green] ;
X = [blue, red] ;
X = [green, green] ;
X = [green, blue] ;
X = [green, red] ;
false.
```

Comment: What have you tried? This code obviously won’t work, also because in Prolog, only variables are capitalized and atoms must be lowercase or quoted appropriately. Have you used `member/2`? It’s also often useful to use `length/2` to make a list of a prescribed length without specifying its contents.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a higher-level view:

```
combinations_( L, N, R) :-
    length( R, N),
    maplist( flip(member,L), R).

flip( P, L, X):- call(P, X, L).
```

We just create a list of length `N` and fill it up with all the elements of `L` one after another.

I first saw `flip` on RosettaCode's [Zebra Puzzle page](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Zebra_puzzle#Alternative_version_2).

Comment: Your answer had a nice insight I didn't see.

Comment: You should add a working example to the answer. When I first saw this I had to test it to verify it worked when N was 1 or greater than 2 and worked with empty list and list of just one item.

Comment: @GuyCoder Somehow it feels very natural and self-evident, to me. :)

Answer (score 0):

This works in SWI-Prolog:

```
all_combos(_, 0, []).

all_combos(L, N, [H|T]) :-
    length([H|T], N),
    N1 is N - 1,
    member(H, L),
    all_combos(L, N1, T).
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the context for reference. code-only answers can become invalid if there's no explanation.

Answer (score -3):

This is a good start :

```
   ?- [user] .

% consulting user_input...

:- op(2'1,'yfx','of') .

(
    _yO_ of _Xs_
)
:-
(
   (
      [] = _Xs_ ; 
   )
   ;
   (
      [_yO_|_xS_] = _Xs_ 
   ) 
   ;
   (
      [_|_xS_] = _Xs_ , 
      _yO_ of _xS_ 
   )
)
.

%^D%

% consulting user_query...

   ?- 
_Xs_ = ['red','green','blue'] , 
_pO_ of _Xs_ , 
_qO_ of _Xs_ , 
Ys = [_pO_,_qO_] .

Ys = [red,red] ? ;
Ys = [red,green] ? ;
Ys = [red,blue] ? ;
Ys = [red,_qO_] ? ;
Ys = [green,red] ? ;
Ys = [green,green] ? ;
Ys = [green,blue] ? ;
Ys = [green,_qO_] ? ;
Ys = [blue,red] ? ;
Ys = [blue,green] ? ;
Ys = [blue,blue] ? ;
Ys = [blue,_qO_] ? ;
Ys = [_pO_,red] ? ;
Ys = [_pO_,green] ? ;
Ys = [_pO_,blue] ? ;
Ys = [_pO_,_qO_] ? ;
false
   ?-
```